# Freezing macos UI for 30 seconds — to meditate

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create a Swift5 macOS app that freezes mac’s UI for 30 seconds every 30 minutes - to force me to meditate.

I've already created a status menu app with a Timer.scheduledTimer. Now I need to freeze the UI so I can’t browse/write/whatever for 30s each time updateTimer() is called.

I have no idea where to start looking. Any help? thanks!

Comment: What I would do is take a screen shot and superimpose the screen shot over everything.

Comment: Show a window sheet with a spinner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`presentationOptions` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428664-presentationoptions) of `NSApplication` to achieve this. Effectively, what you want to do is temporarily enter ["kiosk mode"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009080). The available [presentation options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/presentationoptions) let you disable process switching, etc.

Background apps will continue to show, including updates. You can cover them with your app's own window if you feel the need.

Comment: hi, I'm not good with Swift so I couldn't try this properly... and in the meantime I found the CGCaptureAllDisplays solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep things simple, and invoke the OSX lock screen service by running:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

That will push your computer into lock screen mode (putting all your current work in suspension) and force you to enter your password to get back to it.

You can set this up to run every 30 minutes by using a launch agent. Open a plain-text file in your favorite text editor, and copy in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.timed.lockdown</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession</string>
        <string>-suspend</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1800</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this file as "my.timed.lockdown.plist" (convention is to name the file the same as the *label* string) in the folder "~/Library/LaunchAgents". You can load the job into launchd either by restarting your machine (excessive) or by running the following command in terminal:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.timed.lockdown.plist
```

You can even set a **"Get on the d*mned cushion!"** message on your lock screen, if you think that would be helpful: System preferences->Security & Privacy->General->'Show a message when the screen is locked'.

If you want to do this with a swift app then you could, obviously, but it's such an easy thing to implement with built-in systems...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Here my solution. I setup a timer, and inside:

```
    CGCaptureAllDisplays()
    sleep(30)
    CGReleaseAllDisplays()
```

This blacks out the screen and blocks input for 30s. Exactly what I wanted.

The only problem with this, is if I'm in a FullScreen application (which I'm often), then it half blocks input and doesn't black out the screen.

To circumvent this, I just get out of the fullscreen Space by activating and bringing my main window to front before, then waiting a second for the UI to update:

```
    NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(Meditate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

The Meditate function then does the CGCaptureAllDisplays() stuff as indicated